# Abort tests with nodeunit

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, nodeunit

I am writing unit tests for a database driver. In the first test, I create some object that I then intend to use later in the tests.
I would like to write the tests so that if this (crucial) step fails, everything else just stops.
I did this, but it feels a little too hacky... what are the best practices in this case?

```
"create constructors and layers": function( test ){
  var self = this;

  try {
    self.shared.personLayer = new self.Layer( 'people', {  name: true, surname: true, age: true } );
    test.ok( self.shared.personLayer );

    self.shared.personLayerNoDb = new self.LayerNoDb( 'people', {  name: true, surname: true, age: true }, self.db );
    test.ok( self.shared.personLayerNoDb );

    var personLayerOverwriteDb = new self.Layer( 'people', {  name: true, surname: true, age: true }, self.db );
    test.ok( personLayerOverwriteDb );

    self.shared.ranks = new self.Layer( 'ranks', {  name: true, number: true } );
    test.ok( self.shared.ranks );

  } catch( e ){
    console.log("Error: couldn't create layers, aborting all tests...");
    console.log( e );
    console.log( e.stack );
    process.exit();
  }

  test.done();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Any "crucial step" that is required for all other tests to take place is not a unit test.  Unit tests are supposed to be independent of each other, and in principle can be run in any order.

What you are looking for is a "Before" or "Before Each" hook.

Place your setup code in the `setUp` section, [documented on the nodeunit README](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit)

Comment: So if I want to run a long series of tests all on the same collections, and also want to test the creation of this connection? I mean, every *other* unit test can be independent, but I doubt you go far without a collection, while testing a db...

Comment: Does this solution make enough sense? Or shall I connect/create driver constructor/create driver instance/disconnect for each test? https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer/blob/master/test.js

Comment: Generally speaking for integration tests, you can do very expensive things like creating drivers or connections before the entire _suite_ is run.  Before each _test_ you do things like clearing out database collections.

Comment: Creating drivers and connections is the "crucial step" I was refrring to in my question...